# Grouping array with SQL

Tags: php, arrays

I have written a SQL statement which return the number of rows by workgroup. I want to assign this number to the workgroup in an array. Below is my PHP code, SQL statement, and output:

**SQL:**

```
SELECT workgroup, count([id]) AS num
FROM member
GROUP BY workgroup
ORDER BY workgroup
```

**Output**

```
Workgroup     num
1             28
2             301
3             50
4             12
5             51
6             39
```

I have written PHP script to place the numbers in an array. This is where I am stuck.

**PHP:**

```
    $group = array();
    $sql_query = "SELECT workgroup, count([id]) as num FROM member GROUP BY workgroup order by workgroup";
    $stmt_query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql_query);

    while($row_count = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt_count, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){   
        $group[] = $row_count['num'];   
    }
```

I want to group them in an array in this manner `$group = array("1"=>"28", "2"=>"301", "3"=>"50", "4"=>"12", ...`.

How can I achieve this using PHP?

Comment: `$group[$row_count['workgroup']] = $row_count['num'];`